# Phonegap iOS 10 input type "date" not able to show value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am creating app in phonegap/cordova and i have created form with input type of - text, date.
So

```
<input placeholder="DOB" type="date"  class="form-control profile-page-dob" >
```

Above html was supporting before iOS 10 but as i updated iphone 6s then native datepicker is display but value which i am giving to "type=date" is not displaying but value is there (when i checked through `alert($(".profile-page-dob").val())`  i.e.  1996-05-01 ).

If anybody expert got something Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found some tricky way, because ios10 is showing value of selected date but placeholder is working then I just appended value in placeholder attribute using **change,focusin & focusout** function to handle datepicker value.

```
            $(".profile-page-dob").change(function(){
                // alert(1)
                $(this).attr('type','date')
                $(this).attr('placeholder',$(this).val())
                $(this).attr('value',$(this).val())
                $(this).val($(this).val());
                userDob = $(this).val();                       
                // alert($(".profile-page").html())
            })

            $(".profile-page-dob").focusin(function(){
                $(this).attr('type','date')
                $(this).attr('placeholder',$(this).val())
                $(this).attr('value',$(this).val())
                $(this).val($(this).val())
                userDob = $(this).val();             
            })


            $(".profile-page-dob").focusout(function(){
                $(this).attr('type','date')
                $(this).attr('placeholder',$(this).val())
                $(this).attr('value',$(this).val())
                $(this).val($(this).val())
                userDob = $(this).val();                  
            })
```